# Visual Studio Doesn't Show Hololens Emulator

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens, hololens-emulator

I'm trying to deploy my project to Hololens Emulator using Visual Studio 2017.
My Solution Explorer looks like this:

[My Solution Explorer looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/821KX.png)

[When I try to deploy to my Emulator it shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80XTz.png)

To ensure that the Emulators are working I created a new Blank App (Universal Windows) in Visual Studio, that [showed this Solution Explorer and Deploy options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdtes.png):

The Emulator opened the Blank App [as it's supposed to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81fWo.png).

My Build Settings in Unity are the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgM5q.png).

I've tried to reinstall everything, and even creating new Projects in Unity following Microsoft's official tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/learn-mrtk-tutorials/1-3-exercise-configure-unity-for-windows-mixed-reality?tabs=openxr).

My current Unity version is the 2021.3.21f1 LTS.

Best regards!

Comment: What's the Unity version and XR plugin you are using? Currently, we recommend installing Unity 2020.3 LTS with the Mixed Reality OpenXR plugin for Mixed Reality development, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/choosing-unity-version.

Comment: Besides, the tutorial link you've posted is broken. Please update with the correct one so that we can know which tutorial you are following.

Answer (score 1):

Unity 2021.3.21f1 LTS is not the recommended version. As [Choosing a Unity version and XR plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/choosing-unity-version) said,

> For new projects, we recommend using **Unity 2020.3.31f1** with the latest Mixed Reality OpenXR plugin to avoid this issue.

Besides, as per [Install the tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/install-the-tools), Visual Studio 2019 (16.8 or higher) is needed for Hololens 2 development.